# Best Architecture Model for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

We have a product that just just finished Dev and is running in Beta stage.

We want to now spend time developing it onto a cloud based architecture.

It's a PHP/Node.JS platform with a MySQL DB. Each Tennant has a separate set of settings that load depending upon the hostname used (stored in DB as the web app layer is stateless). There is also a separate master instance used for controlling the child instances.

My idea is as follows:

- Use Amazon Aurora server-less for the DB.
- Have the master instance on it's own dedicated hosting
- For all child instances, have a set of EC2 instances all with the shared virtual host config and then the web app loads the specific settings for that users session based upon the domain name used in the web request. On front of all these have a load balancer and then just enable more instances to be created on the fly as load comes on.

Is this the best way to approach this?

Comment: Why would you host the master instance outside of AWS? Is there some reason you don't think that can run as an EC2 server? You should also make sure you understand the limitations of Aurora serverless. You might be better off with a regular Aurora server depending on how much traffic your product gets.

Comment: Sorry I meant the master “controller” instance but still as  EC2 but outside of the standard pool as it runs it’s own set of services and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface sounds ok. Could you use a tool like this to perhaps make it easier to understand exactly what you are planning?

https://cloudcraft.co

Also, you mention node.js. Using AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda you could make the majority of your stack serverless meaning you would only have to worry about using EC2 instances for your PHP code.

Comment: Again looks ok. A few improvements;
1) You may want to put the EC2's and the DB into a VPC for extra security
2) The "Child instances" as part of an autoscaling group so they number can grow and shrink depending on load